# golang goroutines, chanel and sync.WaitGroup

Tags: go, coroutine

I use simple code, but I get deadlock all the time.
Please explain to the beginner what I am doing wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ok := make(chan int, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            for x := range ok {
                fmt.Println(i, x)
                if x >= 5 {
                    ok <- x - 1
                }
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i, &wg)
    }

    ok <- 1
    ok <- 3
    ok <- 2
    ok <- 5
    ok <- 3
    ok <- 9

    wg.Wait()
}
```

**fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!**

Comment: wg.Wait is waiting for the goroutines to complete.  The goroutines are waiting to receive a value from `ok`.   What your expectation for how the program will terminate?

Comment: I want to use some goroutines for some work, and finish main when no data in chan ok

Comment: i send 6 int to 2 goroutines, while goroutines work - add to them some data

Comment: You need to close the channel to communicate to your downstream goroutines that no more work in expected on that channel. In your case, you are using ok channel in the go routine as well. This makes it nearly impossible to figure out what is the right time to close the channel. Can you detail your use-case more?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Qq2I2jp12ix - Code here works without any issues. You need to figure out how to achieve something similar. If you don't close the channel, the for loop in goroutine will keep blocking.

Comment: i want download some urls by crawler, while get pages, add url to crawler.

Comment: No, i want add to chan while work.

Answer (score 2):

- The background of the problem is that the range operator reads from the channel until the channel is closed. Hence the for-range loop keeps waiting for more input from the channel `ok` even though there are no more inputs to come at some point. At the same time `wg.Wait()` is waiting for the goroutines to finish. Hence a deadlock!
- Either you'll have to close the `ok` channel at some point, where
  there are no more incoming values to the channel `ok`.

Or you may use the worker pool just like,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- "worker process value  " + strconv.Itoa(i)
}

func workerMonitor(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string) {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}

func doWork(ch <-chan string, done chan<- bool) {
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan string)
    var arr = [6]int{1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 9}
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        if arr[i] >= 5 {
            for j := arr[i]; j >= 5; j-- {
                wg.Add(1)
                go worker(&wg, ch, j-1)
            }
        }
        go worker(&wg, ch, arr[i])
    }

    go workerMonitor(&wg, ch)

    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    go doWork(ch, done)
    <-done
}
```

[Play ground url](https://play.golang.org/p/S5geluXoou5)

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I need to run the go application in N threads. Data for the threads is there before the threads start and added data to running coroutines at runtime.